# Sulu cms: Create bundle for custom controller

Tags: symfony, sulu

I am using **sulu minimal edition.**

So i want to create bundle for my custom controllers.
I have contact form in my website.
 On form submit i want redirect to symfony route.
 Save data in custom table and display in admin area user role wise. Whats best way?

I follow http://blog.sulu.io/how-to-develop-a-bundle-in-the-sulu-admin-1
but php on ./bin/websiteconsole debug:router my new routes created in controller not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you use annotations. Dit you try defining your route with XML?

As far as I know annotation - and XML defined routes can't be mixed within the same bundle (some please correct me if I'm wrong). Since Sulu uses XML I'd stick to that for the sake of consistency.

Comment: I want to show listing in admin panel for my custom table. how can i do that?

Comment: Use the NewsBundle you build. You could try to show the data of your form instead of the 'News' by using your forms Entity class. Or edit NewsBundle/Entity/NewsItem.php and generate a form for this entity. 

If you followed the blog-tutorial you should have all the 'building-blocks' to achieve what you want I believe. I'm learning Sulu myself - that would be my approach.

Do you see the route in the meantime? Does your form work?